# OpenXML whitespace removed from text in Actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript, openxml

I'm using Actionscript's XML class to read and modify an Word OpenXML document. For some reason, after I'm done modifying the XML, converting it back to a string removes whitespaces from text nodes. Actually, that's not really true, because the unmodified XML document also doesn't have those spaces, but they still show up in the word document. In fact, if all I do with the document's content is parse it with the XML parser and then convert it back to a string, the only difference between the untouched XML and the one that went through the parser is that the `xml:` namespace prefix is stripped out from the `space` attribute of the `w:t` nodes.

Sample of the Untouched XML:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0012761D" w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6" w:rsidRDefault="0012761D" w:rsidP="004F0FA6">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Distance</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>at</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">SL, ISA, MTOW</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Sample from the XML that went through Actionscript's parser:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0012761D" w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6" w:rsidRDefault="0012761D" w:rsidP="004F0FA6">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t space="preserve">Distance</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>at</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004F0FA6">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Gotham Book" w:hAnsi="Gotham Book"/>
            <w:b w:val="0"/>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t space="preserve">SL, ISA, MTOW</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

The first sample produce "Distance at SL, ISA, MTOW" while the document for the second sample produce "DistanceatSL, ISA, MTOW".

As you can see, the only difference is between `<w:t xml:space="preserve">Distance</w:t>` and `<w:t space="preserve">Distance</w:t>`.
So I tried manually adding the `xml:` prefix to the space attributes, but that doesn't have any effect.

I also tried to set the `prettyPrinting` property of the XML class to `false` but it somehow corrupts the document.

Is there something else that could be responsible for those missing spaces?

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more of the XML, especially the part that contains the namespace definitions. As far as I know, the part you are showing is not valid XML. (it's an XMLList fom AS3 perspective at most)

Comment: Your problem is the suppression of the "xml" prefix.

`xml:space='preserve'` indicates to keep spaces, `space='preserve'` means nothing, so spaces are not displayed anymore.

Comment: yes that is what I also thought about. by having a look at the complete XML structure, I hoped to get additional information about the configured namespaces, to maybe have an idea why this namespace gets removed.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the formatting in my sample(the `</w:p>` closing tag was invisible). The samples constitute one `w:p` node of a `w:tc` node in a `w:tr` node in a `w:tbl` node in the `w:body` node in the `w:document` node. I did try adding the `xml:` prefix to the `space` attributes, without results.

Comment: The whole XML structure is massive.

Comment: Here are the namespace declarations: http://pastebin.com/45Eab4uj .

Comment: To be clear, currently, the samples taken before and after parsing and editing are actually identical.

Comment: Does your last comment mean, you solved the problem or is this related to the pastebin? Anyway, the pastebin doesn't have the namespace xml defined. please look for `xmlns:xml` in your XML and tell paste what it is assigned to.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved, even though the xml are identical. I don't think the xml namespace needs(or should) be declared in an openxml file. When the Actionscript parser automatically adds declarations for this namespace, Word complains that it shouldn't have a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the `xmlns:xml`:

The W3C states in the document [**Namespaces in XML 1.1** under section 3 **Declaring Namespaces**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#ns-decl):

> **Namespace constraint: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names**
>
> The prefix **xml** is by definition bound to the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. It *MAY*, but need not, be declared, and *MUST NOT* be undeclared or bound to any other namespace name. Other prefixes *MUST NOT* be bound to this namespace name, and it *MUST NOT* be declared as the default namespace.

I searched for [actionscript XML xmlns:xml](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=actionscript+XML+xmlns%3Axml) and experimented a bit with the topic,
to find out, that Actionscript seems to know about that namespace implicitly, but seems to assume it as the default namespace. so when it gets put "printed" the according attributes dont have a namespace anymore.

What you can do is to explicitely set the namespace correctly using the addNamespace on the XML instance. The resulting XML will then contain all atributes correctly and will contain the namespace declaration.

If you don't want the namespace declaration then before storing the result you can remove the declaration from the string via replace method.

I [tested it using this code](http://wonderfl.net/c/6CQe) (*I adopted the order of code and output to make more sense when displayed here or used somewhere else*):

```
var xml:XML = <data/>;
xml.appendChild(<element xml:attr="what"/>);
trace('without explicit namespace:');
trace(xml); 

xml.addNamespace(new Namespace("xml","http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"));
trace('after adding xml namespace:');
trace(xml);

trace('removing the xml ns from the string of the correct XML');
trace(xml.toXMLString().replace(' xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"',''))
```

it produces the following output:

***without explicit namespace:***

```
<data>
  <element attr="what" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
</data>
```

***after adding xml namespace:***

```
<data xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
  <element xml:attr="what"/>
</data>
```

***removing the xml ns from the String of the correct XML***

```
<data>
  <element xml:attr="what"/>
</data>
```